# How to cancel a postDelay Handler

Tags: android, handler

I have a splash screen "intro" activity, that just shows the title of the App. and brief info about the developer and it has a `button` named "skip". I created a `postHandler` so that, the main activity starts automatically after 3 seconds. Or, the main activity should starts when the `skip` button is pressed. If the "skip" `button` is pressed it should invalidate/remove the `postHandled callbacks`. But what happens is, even after I press the "skip" `button` and moved to the main Activity, the main activity starts one more time again, as if, the `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);` is not called. I just want when I press the "skip `button` to move to the main Activity once and it should not start again when the "skip" `button` is pressed. Please see the code below, and let me know what is wrong or missing.

Code:

```
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent01 =  new Intent(Intro.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent01);
            finish();
        }
    };
    ....
    ....
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    introButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
            Intent intent00 = new Intent(Intro.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent00);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your logic in onDestroy()

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        Log.d("Callbacks", "Removed");
    }
```